# Calling a function when a user comeback to a page from a different tab in react js app

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a function to authorize a user when it comes back from a different tab or opens the browser which is minimized. How can I do this in react js app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.hasFocus` function. It is native and works and all browsers.

You can see in this [example](https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/Yxxzdj)